# SQL Check constraint on column referencing other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I want to limit a column that it can only have a value when another column has a value.

example: (this doesn't work)

```
create table testConstraint (
col1 int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
col2 int,
col3 int check (col2 is not null),
col4 int)
```

This is not possible because he cannot reference another column.
Error:

> Column CHECK constraint for column 'col3' references another column,
>   table 'testConstraint'.

Another try was: (also doesn't work)

```
create table testConstraint (
col1 int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
col2 int,
col3 int,
col4 int)
GO

alter table testConstraint add constraint ck_columnNotNull check (case when col2 is null then col3 is null end)
GO
```

Anyone have an idea how this would be possible with a constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a trigger.

Also, you can try this

(1)

```
ALTER TABLE TestConstraint ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_TestConstraint CHECK (NOT ( (col3 is not null) and (col2 is null) ))
GO
```

or this

(2)

```
ALTER TABLE TestConstraint ADD CONSTRAINT
CK_TestConstraint CHECK 
(
    ((col3 is not null) and (col2 is not null)) or 
    ((col3 is null) and (col2 is null))
)
GO
```

depending on what exactly you need.

I just tested it and it works OK, I think.

```
insert into 
TestConstraint
(col2, col3, col4)
values
(null, 1, 2)

-- ERROR

insert into 
TestConstraint
(col2, col3, col4)
values
(1, 1, 2)

-- OK
```

Comment: for elaboration: col2 is a foreign key that allows NULL. But col3 may only have a value when col2 has one. I know it's possible with a trigger but I hoped it would also be possible with a constraint. I find triggers are more dangerous then constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE testConstraint
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_columnNotNull
CHECK ( 1 = CASE
                WHEN col2 IS NULL AND col3 IS NULL THEN 1 
                WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END)
```

Comment: I think he wants to error out only when "col3 is not null" but "col2 is null". Your expression does something different. Also, it can be simplified to - see (2) in my answer.

Comment: @peter.petrov: You might have right, tom can put any condition in WHEN clause.

Answer (score 0):

Only simple logic is required, plus it needs (as per your second attempt) to be a table check constraint, so you can't declare it inline with the declaration of `col3`:

```
create table testConstraint (
col1 int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
col2 int,
col3 int,
col4 int)
GO

alter table testConstraint add constraint ck_columnNotNull check (
   col3 is null
or col2 is not null
)
GO
```

If `col3` is `null`, then we don't *care* what the value of `col2` is. Conversely, if it's *not* `NULL`, then we do want to enforce the `col2` *isn't* null. That's what the two sides of the `or` effectively give us.